# How to dislplay Serverside-JS search results from MarkLogic on HTML

Tags: javascript, marklogic, marklogic-9

I am newbie to Javascript and MarkLogic 9.
Currently, am trying to display searched
results in HTML via Server-side Javascript.
(not client node.js API)

Query results seem fine if I access
directly to .sjs file from browser, but
am not able to make it as func() and
run from HTML (presentation layer).
HTML and .sjs files are both hosted in ML server)

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Include your code and what you tried so far in the post. Take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for more information.

Comment: can you show some SJS code please?

Answer (score 2):

> Query results seem fine if I access directly to .sjs file from
>   browser, but am not able to make it as func() and run from HTML
>   (presentation layer). HTML and .sjs files are both hosted in ML
>   server)
>
> Could anyone help me?

Use Javascript fetch() function. The correct code for what you are trying to achieve could look something like this:

```
var payload = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
};

var data = new FormData();
data.append( "json", JSON.stringify( payload ) );

fetch("/echo/json/",
{
    method: "POST",
    body: data
})
.then(function(res){ return res.json(); })
.then(function(data){ alert( JSON.stringify( data ) ) })
```

Comment: Appreciate for your quick response. Why document.write function does not work in this case?